# Features for Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, time-series, data

I try to understand my time series data. I have temperature values measured with a sampling rate of 10.000 values / 1 second. So I measure in 1 second 10.000 different temperature values. So I have a vector x with length 10.000. This I repeat with certain time intervals. Since the vectors are big, I want to create subsequences of them for my model later to predict. But now I do not understand if I have to see the whole time series data with a shape (number of samples, vector x length) or (number of samples*vector x length, 1) to move on.

Comment: What is the sampling rate of your temperature sensor. In the question you claim 1Hz and 10,000Hz. Which is it? Use standard units to explain your dataset such that the question is clear. Furthermore, what do you want your LSTM to predict, future temperature values I presume?

Comment: @JahKnows the sampling rate is here 10.000 values /1 second. I want the lstm predict future temperature values right, this in combination with a sequential lstm to learn from the feature(s). And thats the point I do not understand. Do I have 1 feature(temperature) or 10.000 features for each sampling ?

Comment: @JahKnows do you have an idea about my question ?

Comment: no I do not understand at all what you are trying to ask. This seems like a "I have a method and I want to use it for my use case" rather than a "I would like to resolve this problem". Can you explain clearly what is your specific problem please? Leave out the LSTM and all that for now we will get there later. What do you have and what do you want to do?

Comment: @JahKnows I updated my post without the lstm. I want to create subsequences since my vectors are too long to use for prediction, but I do not understand if I have 1 feature or 10.000 features with the same unit. I hope this is a bit more clear.